# general error handling message for different projects template

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have the following class which writes new line to a text file.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace TextStreamer
{
    class TextWriter
    {
        private string _FilePath;
        private string _TextToAdd;

        // Constructor will assign file Path variable and check if file is valid
        public TextWriter(string filePath)
        {
            this._FilePath = filePath;  
            ValidateFile(); 
        } 

        // Validate if the text file exist
        private void ValidateFile()
        {
            // If file does not exist show error message 
            // and create new text file
            if(!File.Exists(_FilePath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not found");   
                File.Create(_FilePath);
                Console.WriteLine("Created new file {0}", _FilePath);  
            }
        }

        // Write new line to the text file
        public void WriteNewLine(string text)
        {
            this._TextToAdd = text + Environment.NewLine;
            File.AppendAllText(_FilePath, _TextToAdd);
        }
    }
}
```

Right now if the file does not exist it will write a message to the console and then it will create the text file, but what if i used say WPF application, in this case i prefer showing a message box with the same message, how can i achieve that.

I tried throwing exception FileNotFoundException but that just crashes the program and exit.

Comment: I don't really understand. So, you want to show a message box instead of console log?

Comment: @Kamdroid when using the class with console application project I want the message to be shown on console, but when using WPF application the message to be shown inside a message box, so is there a way to generalize the error and leaving the class user to decide how to show the error

Comment: I've posted a simple way of how you can do this - let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this is by using a public variable to change the option to console log or show message.

Add the namespace for the generic message box:

```
using System.Windows;
```

And add a public variable in your class that will let you programmatically change the logging method, such as:

```
public bool UseMsgBox = false;
```

You could improve this by using things like using an `int` or `enum` to have more logging methods, though a `bool` is fine for only 2 options.

Add a logging method such as:

```
private void LogMsg(string msg)
{
    if(UseNsgBox) MessageBox.Show(msg);
    else Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

And replace your `Console.WriteLine`'s with `LogMsg` instead.

Make sure to change the option when you create your class:

```
TextWriter textWriter = new TextWriter("SomeFile.txt");
textWriter.UseMsgBox = true; // or false
```

Actually, this might not work as you instantly call the `LogMsg` when your class is created, so perhaps add it as an initialization parameter as well:

```
 public TextWriter(string filePath, bool useMsgBox = false)
 {
     UseMsgBox = useMsgBox;
     // ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, so I think I can place that in the constructor so one line of code will be required ? ```var tw = new TextWriter(path, true)```

Comment: Yep, you can also make `UseMsgBox` private if you only want it set from the constructor. (Consider renaming to `useMsgBox` or `_useMsgBox` depending how you like to name things)